# Gumby framework - mobile nav doesn't work

Tags: mobile, navigation, css-frameworks, gumby-framework

I'm starting to build a new portfolio with this Gumby framework. I've chosen Gumby because I like SASS more than LESS, so I would like to try a framework based on this language.
The problem is that the mobile navigation doesn't work for me.

If I use the ui.html inside the downloaded package and I resize the browser window, the "three lines icon" appears, but if I click nothing happend!

If I use the Gumby's UI demo on the website it works...either for some website I saw here on stackoverflow that use gumby!

I've checked all the paths, the developer told me that I have to use gumby.min.js and it's uncomment by default, so i don't know why this mobile menu doesn't work for me.

Maybe I have to work online with the website hosted on a server? But I'ts strange...
I don't know what code to post, because it's simply the ui.html who all of you can find inside the downloaded gumby package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know javascript well so I cannot explain how/why this works but there is an issue with toggleswitch.js. Add e.stopImmediatePropagation(); to line 45. That's what worked for me.

If someone knows how or why this works I would love to learn.